# Basic hibernate persistance

Tags: hibernate, spring

I have a mapped POJO which I need to persist. In that POJO I have another POJO, bound with foreign key.
Now, when I create a new object and persist it with Hibernate, does the Hibernate also persist the embedded POJO or I have to do it manually?
Basically the question is regarding "reverse-cascading".

In my case this doesn't happen, and I get an exception if I don't persist the embedded POJO beforehand.

Edit: Here are some code, I omitted some of the details (setters & getters):
This is the Person Class, as you can see, it has an Address class embedded in it.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    protected Address address;
    protected String privateName;
    ...
    /* More members */

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public Address getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Column(name = "private_name", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getPrivateName() {
        return this.privateName;
    }

    public void setPrivateName(String privateName) {
        this.privateName = privateName;
    }
}
```

This is the Address class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id; 
    private Country country;
    private State state;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private String number;
    private String postcode;
    private float longitude;
    private float latitude;

    public Address() {
    }

    public Address(Integer id, Country countries, String city, String street,
        String number, String postcode, float longitude, float latitude) {
    this.id = id;
    this.country = countries;
    this.city = city;
    this.street = street;
    this.number = number;
    this.postcode = postcode;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "state")
    public State getState() {
    return this.state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
    this.state = state;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country", nullable = false)
    public Country getCountry() {
    return this.country;
    }  
}
```

Here is the Hibernate Configuration I'm using with Spring:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:my_db;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS my_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.tra.la.bla" />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Can you share your hbm.xml files?

Comment: Hibernate will certainly persist both of these objects as long as you've mapped them correctly. We'll need to see the classes and any Hibernate configuration to explain why it's not happening.

Comment: Do you mean 'embedded' in a way that Entity A consists Entity B or do you mean Embedded type, so Entity A consist Embedded B?

Comment: @Alex, I added the classes for you to see

Comment: @Mellowcandle, did you try answer by JB Nizet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a persist is not cascaded unless you tell Hibernate to do it with

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-transitive

Answer (score 0):

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
public Address getAddress() {
    return this.address;
}
```

Maybe above code solve your problem

You could say how hibernate acts on connected POJOs using like some code above.

I hope it helps

Comment: I don't have a clue what you're talking about. can you explain ?